# Google Cloud Print server gcp-cups-connector wants password for user gcp

Tags: printing, upstart

I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Printer server using CUPS Connector on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 computer and the Google-provided gcp-cups-connector executable. I followed the instruction of the [wiki](https://github.com/google/cups-connector/wiki/Configuration) and created a user gcp as described [here](https://github.com/google/cups-connector/wiki/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi-Raspbian-Jessie) and an init file. I installed the upstart script which fails.

```
sudo useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin -r -M gcp
```

When I try to run the connector from the CLI it askes for a password (for gcp I guess) which I dont have, and an empty pw is not accepted:

```
exec su -l -s /bin/sh -c "~/GCP/gcp-cups-connector -config-filename ~/GCP/gcp-cups-connector.config.json" gcp
password:
```

Is this a cups authorisation problem?
If I run the connector as a normal user, it also askes a pw (which I know an enter). Then all works fine. But it prevents the automatic run from upstart.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer: One can't `su` to a `nologin` user as a normal user, but invoking it as superuser it works, no password asked.

Anyways, this whole thing came about because this command was to run as an upstart job (which is executed as root) and failed consistently during boot. So I tried to debug it from the CLI.

It could be interesting to note that on my system (Ubuntu 14.04), the /etc/init/gcp.conf script didn't work in it's wiki version, I had to add a pause of 40 sec to reliably launch it at boot time:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
pre-start script
        sleep 40
end script

exec su -l -s /bin/sh -c "/home/<user>/GCP/gcp-cups-connector \
-config-filename /home/<user>/GCP/gcp-cups-connector.config.json" gcp
```